# select rows based on multiple criteria in moving window of 3

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, conditional-statements

My dataframe has four variables.

```
DF <- read.table(text="  v1       v2      v3      v4
 175     14.842   3.06   3300.00
 176     0.777    3.21   80
 177     4.770    4.15   39.28
 178     10.450   6.24   50.36
 179     0.507    6.27   0.48
 180     0.037    3.31  -47.21
 181     15.627   6.28   89.73
 182     57.856   16.90  169.11
 183     26.457   20.10  70
 184     1.482    20.29  0.95
 185     0.842    20.45  0.79", header=TRUE)
```

In a moving window of 3 i.e. (175,176,177), (176,177,178),(177,178,179), (178,179,180)  and so on, in the column v4, I want to print the middle row if all three v4 are > -30. For example, if v4 in 175,176,177 are all > -30, then store 176, if v4 in (176,177,178) are all greater than > -30 , then store 177 and so on.

The following code (courtesy of Roland) does the job. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453810/test-criteria-for-a-moving-window-of-3-rows-in-a-data-frame/24454255#24454255.

```
ind <- DF$v4 > -30
ind <- filter(ind, rep(1, 3)) == 3L
ind[is.na(ind)] <- FALSE
DF[ind, ]
#   v1     v2    v3     v4
#2 176  0.777  3.21  80.00
#3 177  4.770  4.15  39.28
#8 182 57.856 16.90 169.11
```

However I need to make a slight change in the code. Other than all the three v4 being > -30, value of v3 for the first (of the three) should be greater than 2.5. For example, in (175,176,177) if  v4 > -30 for all of them and v3 > 2.5 for 175, the store 176. For (176,177,178), if v4 > -30 for all three and v3 < 2.5 for 176, then do not store 177.

Thanks again.

Comment: So where is your code? Doesn't matter if it's not right yet, but surely you have already attempted this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(zoo)

 ok <- function(ix) with(DF[ix, ], all(v4 > -30) & v3[1] > 2.5)
 DF[ rollapply(1:nrow(DF), 3, ok, fill = FALSE), ]
```

giving:

```
    v1     v2    v3     v4
2  176  0.777  3.21  80.00
3  177  4.770  4.15  39.28
4  178 10.450  6.24  50.36
8  182 57.856 16.90 169.11
9  183 26.457 20.10  70.00
10 184  1.482 20.29   0.95
```

Note that `v3` is always greater than 2.5 in the example data so that condition has no effect here.